# How to create an alias for the whole table produced by NATURAL JOIN?

Tags: oracle, alias

```
SELECT A.ename FROM (emp NATURAL JOIN dept) A;
```

This produces `ERROR at line 1: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended`.

Finally I was able to achieve this in a little bit more elaborate way:

```
SELECT A.ename FROM (SELECT * FROM emp NATURAL JOIN dept) A;
```

This works, but I suspect there must be a simpler way to do this, that would not require nesting queries. Is that so?

Answer (score 2):

@Robert Merkwürdigeliebe right, it is not good to use NATURAL JOIN because if you will add columns with same name and type in both tables, your join will works different way than now.

But if you still want to practice in NATURAL JOIN - you can give aliases to each table but when you will call columns (in any part of SELECT statment) - you can't use this aliases. So in fact you don't need table aliases

```
SELECT d.department_id
FROM employees e NATURAL JOIN departments d;

ORA-25155: column used in NATURAL join cannot have qualifier
```

BUT

```
SELECT department_id, last_name
FROM employees e NATURAL JOIN departments d;
```

works

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer : never use natural joins!

Instead explicitly define the joins. Natural joins do things automagically for you and thus are error prone. Not a good thing when programming.